# Export the drop off rate for all the pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, analytics-api

I want to export the drop off rate information from user flow in GA.

The only way to see this information appears to be to actually click in each "group" within the user flow dashboard to see this information.

Does anybody know if this information could be taken from Google Analytics API? Or if there is an alternative way to get/export this information?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a terminology problem.   They call it "drop off rate" in the user flow report but they call it "exits" in other places.

There is an entire report that does exactly what you want.   It tells you how many people dropped of or "exited" for each page on your site.   It is available from:  "Behavior" -> "Site Content" -> "Exit Pages".

You can view the data in Google Analytics just by scrolling down, or you can use the "Export" dropdown near the top of the page.